# how to give the different colours of the text in the document that is different from predefined colours availble in latex

Tags: color

Need to give `color` with different tone for the `header border` and text in document, had given the code like this

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=2.54cm,right=1cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.5cm,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{\color{blue}\rule[-0.75cm]{\paperwidth}{1cm}}
    \AtPageLowerLeft{\color{gray}\rule[-0.3cm]{\paperwidth}{1cm}}
                     }
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{contents}\\
}
\flushleft
This is my first document for latex


\end{document}
```

It is showing the error as  `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor`.

[The color I got]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0gOl.png)

But I need the color in this tone
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` with `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}`

Generally, this happens when some other package is also loading xcolor with different options. I am not sure why you are loading xcolor 3 times? This itself will result in options clash.

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

Just load it once, with the correct options.

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

Comment: I had tried with the package , that you had mentioned but getting the same error, please 
 help me to change the tone of the blue color to dark blue color as like as seen in the secound image

Comment: Got the result, thank you very much for helping.